# R , how to stack and keep factor

Tags: r

R question:
How do I stack two or more columns of numbers **and** keep a factor as well

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
patient analyte1value analyte2value analyte3value  
pt1 1 3 5  
pt2 2 6 7  
pt3 9 10 2  
...
```

I know I can use `stack(select=c(columnnames))`, but I lose the patient factor.

I want to get out:

```
pt1 1 analyte1  
pt1 3 analyte2  
pt1 5 analyte3  
pt2 2 analyte1  
pt2 6 analyte2  
...
```

(I have a sneaking suspicion that I need plyr or something like that...)

thanks.

Answer (score 8):

One option is one of Hadley's other packages: `reshape2`:

```
> require(reshape2)
> dat
  patient analyte1 analyte2 analyte3
1     pt1        1        3        5
2     pt2        2        6        7
3     pt3        9       10        2
> melt(dat, id = "patient")
  patient variable value
1     pt1 analyte1     1
2     pt2 analyte1     2
3     pt3 analyte1     9
4     pt1 analyte2     3
5     pt2 analyte2     6
6     pt3 analyte2    10
7     pt1 analyte3     5
8     pt2 analyte3     7
9     pt3 analyte3     2
> str(melt(dat, id = "patient"))
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ patient : Factor w/ 3 levels "pt1","pt2","pt3": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
 $ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "analyte1","analyte2",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
 $ value   : int  1 2 9 3 6 10 5 7 2
```

One can do this in a more long-winded fashion using `reshape()` from base R:

```
reshape(dat, direction = "long", sep = "", varying = 2:4,
        times = names(dat)[2:4], idvar = "patient",
        timevar = "variable", v.names = "value")
```

with the main difference being that `variable` isn't a factor with base `reshape()`. I presume the user-unfriendliness of that was a motivation for writing `reshape2`...

Comment: thanks!  Hadley code to the rescue. The guy deserves a medal.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to `reshape` your dataframe to a long format.

```
reshape(df,varying=list(2:4),times=names(df)[2:4],
  idvar="patient",v.names="value",direction="long")
```